# How to know whether it is better to classify a predictor variable as categorical or continuous in a glm?

Tags: r, glm

I am working with glm and built this model :
`glm(cbind(Number_F,Nbre_dead)~ Temperature*Transect*Elevation + Size + Number_I, data=marine_data, family=binomial(link=logit))`

Response variable 'cbind(Number_alive, Number_dead)' correspond to the number of individuals, alive and dead, at the end of the experiment.

I already transformed some variables so that the program consider them as categorical and not continuous, such as:

```
marine_data$Elevation<-as.factor(marine_data$Elevation)
marine_data$Transect<-as.factor(marine_data$Transect)
marine_data$Size<-as.factor(marine_data$Size)
```

However, I do not really get why is it better to have some variables being categorical and not continuous ? In my data, 'Size' corresponds to a variable that can take only two values (two categories of Size: 4-5mm and 6-7mm), so for that variable, that seemed quite logical to me it should be categorial. For 'Transect', there is also two categories only (transect 1; transect 2). For variable 'Elevation', I have 3 populations in each Transect and these inhabit similar elevations (~200m, ~800m, ~1600m) between the two transects. There is thus also only 3 'categories' for this variable.

Am I right to consider the variables categorical and not continuous ?

In the model, the other variables are:
'Temperature', that correpsonds to the temperature treatment (6 different treatments) AND 'Number_I', that corresponds to the initial density of individuals, i.e. at the beginning of the experiment.

Should I classify them as categorical too ? What are the pros and cons of each approach ?

Thank you.

Comment: [This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/213722/categorizing-continuous-random-variable-in-logistic-regression) might help you. The main reason I know for categorizing variables in logistic regression is to make it easier to interpret results, but I'm not an expert.